# How to send data back and forth between the Pi and a C# application on a Windows PC

Tags: hardware, camera, sensor, pci

I want to connect the Raspberry Pi to a few sensors and motors and then control it via a C# application I have written. After it has carried out the operation I want the Pi to send back data from the sensors so that I can work with it in the C# application.

What is the best way to do this, and what language should I use to write the program running on the Pi to control the sensors? I know Java, C and C# and I could learn Python if I need too.

Answer (score 2):

There will be dozens of ways of doing what you want.

One of the simpler methods would be to use my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.  A [daemon](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html) runs on the Pi and communicates with the [pigpio Python module](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html) running on a networked Windows or Mac or Linux PC.

This would allow complete control over the remote Pi's gpios and let you control motors (DC, steppers, servos etc.) and read sensors (I2C, SPI, discrete, etc).

You can also talk to the Pi daemon via its socket interface with C or Java, but currently Python is the best integrated.